# how to get Entity type from Mono<Entity>?

Tags: mono, spring-webflux

how correctly operate getter/setter with mono object

```
Mono<Product> productMono = webClient.get()
            .uri(catalogUrl + "/{productId}", productId)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(Product.class)
            .onErrorResume(err -> Mono.empty())
            .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new NoSuchProductException()));
```

then i want to transform my "productMono" POJO to product. thnak you for answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to access to Product instance is using map() operation like this:

```
@GetMapping("/products/{productId}")
  public Mono<MappedProduct> getProduct(@PathVariable("productId") String productId) {
    return webClient.get()
      .uri(catalogUrl + "/{productId}", productId)
      .retrieve()
      .bodyToMono(Product.class)
      .onErrorResume(err -> Mono.empty())
      .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new NoSuchProductException()));
      .map(product -> productMapper(product));   // <-- here you can handle Product instance

  }
```